# C# Project Reference DLL not found on Azure web role (published from Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, azure, dll, visual-studio-2015

I have an issue with DLLs where one web role run well and the other isn't due to failure to load a DLL which both of them use.

I have a few web roles projects, one named A.B and the other named A.B.C.
Both of them reference a lib project named A.Lib.
Running locally works.

After uploading a build to Azure, one web role runs well (A.B.C) while the other (A.B) can't seem to load due to DLL missing (A.Lib).

I have tried to create a new web role named D which was exactly the same as A.B.C but named D both of web roles D & A.B worked well.

Any ideas???

Here is log from web role's fusion log (pulled from windows event viewer):

```
Unable to determine role entry point type from provided Assembly. Process ID: 3176, Process Name: WaIISHost Role entrypoint could not be created: System.TypeLoadException: Unable to load the role entry point due to the following exceptions:
-- System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'A.Lib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' 
or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'A.Lib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

Assembly manager loaded from:  D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  E:\base\x64\WaIISHost.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = A.Lib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///E:/approot/bin
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = E:\approot\bin
Calling assembly : A.B, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: E:\base\x64\WaIISHost.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///E:/approot/bin/A.Lib.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///E:/approot/bin/A.Lib/A.Lib.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///E:/approot/bin/A.Lib.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///E:/approot/bin/A.Lib/A.Lib.EXE.

-- System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'A.Lib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'A.Lib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

Assembly manager loaded from:  D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  E:\base\x64\WaIISHost.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = A.Lib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///E:/approot/bin
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = E:\approot\bin
Calling assembly : A.B, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: E:\base\x64\WaIISHost.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: The same bind was seen before, and was failed with hr = 0x80070002.

 ---> System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes()
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.GetRoleEntryPoint(Assembly entryPointAssembly)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.GetRoleEntryPoint(Assembly entryPointAssembly)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.CreateRoleEntryPoint(RoleType roleTypeEnum)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.InitializeRoleInternal(RoleType roleTypeEnum)
```

**Solution**:
I found that A.B.C referenced A.B and thus caused this issue, I still do not understand why... these two (A.B & A.B.C) were on two completely different VMs.
So in case anyone is experiencing this issue make sure that one project does not contain a reference to the other.

Comment: Do you have  a try to check the dll in the folder or  republish the project? According to your discription, it seems that there is no relateship to code issue.

Comment: Yes, I logged into the VM itself and noticed that inside the bin folder the DLL is missing... I've also tried to deploy to another cloud service yet no luck, also tried multiple times to republish on a current build and republish after deleting the current build. Nothing helped. I started wondering maybe the issue is related to the fact that both have same namespace - A.B and A.B.C and the possibility that this is what is causing this chaos